# Is there a term for the feeling that an object does not weigh enough?

Tags: single-word-requests

When I handle small objects, if they don't weigh as much as my brain thinks they should I sometimes get the impression that they are low quality and perhaps cheap.

I believe a term that might be used when they have sufficient weight is 'gravitas'.  Is there a similar term for the opposite,  when something lacks sufficient substance, weight or gravitas?

The latin root of 'Gravitas' is 'gravis' meaning heavy, serious, troublesome, hard or grave.  "Gravitas" conveys an impression of seriousness, weight or importance.  The word I am looking for would similarly convey an impression of a lack of substance, lack of heft, insignificance, triviality, paltriness or unimportance.

Comment: The Unbearable Lightness of Being?

Comment: @DJClayworth "My new cell phone has a lot of unbearable lightness of being".  Hmm.  Don't know that it works for me :)

Comment: Lightweight, downy, flimsy, fluffy, gossamery, inconsequential, insubstantial, slight.

Comment: You wouldn't use "gravitas" to describe an object's physical weight; it's used to describe figuratively a "weight of importance".

Comment: I think you should edit your question because as it stands, it is completely self-contradictory and liable to mislead people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One might say that the device feels "**slight**".  This sense of the word is defined by [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slight) as "deficient in weight, solidity, or importance".

Answer (score 5):

When you pick up an object that feels solid and substantial, a somewhat common idiom would be "Feel the heft!".  Conversely, if something is lighter in weight than expected, it can be said to ***"lack heft"***.

Definition of ["heft"](https://www.google.com/#q=heft) from Google dictionary:

> 1. the weight of someone or something.
>
> synonyms: weight, heaviness, bulk  "the heft of the urn surprised us"

Comment: Thanks Kristina.  Heft is also a reasonable answer - but I'm looking for a word that conveys a lack of both quality/importance and solidity/weight in the same way that "gravitas" does.

Answer (score 2):

I think **chintzy** is the best word for what you describe:

From Merriam-Webster:

> poorly or cheaply done or made : of low quality

Comment: This is also a good answer - if I could accept two I'd take both 'chintzy' and 'slight'.  They both cover most of my concept.  Or maybe ... "This cell phone is some slintzy chight"

Answer (score 1):

Since you're looking for an antonym to **gravitas** here are some:

**triviality**

[Oxford dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/triviality)

> 1: Lack of seriousness or importance; insignificance:

*the mediocrity and triviality of current popular culture*

---

**trifling**

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/trifling)

> 1. of very little importance; trivial; insignificant:
> 2. of small value, cost, or amount:
>      a trifling sum.
> 3. frivolous; shallow; light:

---

**insubstantial**

[Oxford learner's dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/insubstantial)

> not very large, strong or important

---

**lightweight**

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lightweight)

> 2. being lighter in weight, texture, etc., than another item or object of identical use, quality, or function:
>
> *a lightweight topcoat; a lightweight alloy for ship construction.*

---

**weightless**

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/weightless)

> being without apparent weight, as a freely falling body or a body acted upon by a force that neutralizes gravitation.

---

**featherweight**

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/featherweight)

> 4. extremely light in weight

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bobby.  While it's a reasonable answer I don't believe 'lightweight' conveys the same "importance" factor that "gravitas" does.  I'm specifically looking for something that speaks about your impression of something or a feeling, not a physical property.

Comment: @Tibrogargan ~ the title speaks specifically towards physical weight, so maybe you should edit it

Comment: Well, I'm not positive that "gravitas" can be applied to an object, so I didn't use it in the title.  The body of the question clarifies the requirements.

Comment: @Tibrogargan ~ you're right that it can't; gravitas is used to describe people or situations/events. I don't think there is a word that specifically describes the feeling you get

Comment: I think "trifling" or "paltry" (or even "trumpery", ha) might be the closest I have found when looking up antonyms and synonyms myself - but neither really convey anything about weight.

Comment: @Tibrogargan ~ you just said you weren't looking for a word on physical weight...Please edit your question so it clearly states what you're looking for. The word gravitas itself has nothing to do with physical weight.

Comment: I would disagree.  Here's the wikipedia entry: [Gravitas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitas) - which specifically mentions weight, as does the question title.  The body of my question even mentions physical weight as part of the example.

Comment: @Tibrogargan ~ The Latin literal translation is not how the word has evolved to come to mean seriousness in English. Please refer to Oxford dictionaries: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/gravitas Here you specifically stated that you're not looking for a physical quality: "I'm specifically looking for something that speaks about your impression of something or a feeling, not a physical property." so please edit your question to clearly state what it is you're looking for